# Weird core data storage issue while integrating adwhirl

Tags: iphone, objective-c, adwhirl

I am using core data for local storage in my application. 
But when I am integration adwhirl sdk and framework required for it in my application, it is somehow affect local storage to core data and application gets crash with following message.
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'"

Moreover this crash is not due to I have changed something in my modal classes. I have reset my simulator and checked many times. It is affecting after adwhirl integration only.

Does any framework required for adwhirl affects coredata framework?? Anybody has ever faced such issue ever?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: post some code with lines where the crash occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out some table name conflict, probably due to same/similar name used in that framework. I changed table name it and it's working now.